# Set html tab as active on window reload

Tags: tab, html5, angularjs

I am using the html **tab** tag to show different tabs in my salesforce page. When I am on my second tab, an operation requires me to reload the window. I use window.loaction.reload() for the same.

But unfortunately, when I reload the window the control gets shifted to first tab. Is there a way I can set the second tab as active on window reload?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of window.loaction.reload() use window.location.href=window.location.pathname + '?activeTab=second', then you should have additional JS code for retreiving url param:

window.onload = function(){
      var activeTab = decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]activeTab=([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).replace(/+/g, '%20'))||null;
if(activeTab === 'second'){//activate first tab} else {//do something?}
}

Additionally, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) is a solution how to retrieve url parameter using JS so that use it instead of JS code mentioned above.